# Unable to Load Vanilla GeoJSON in Openlayers 5

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

I'm starting with some valid GeoJSON which I've built using https://geojson.io. My desire is to load it in an Openlayers 5 map.

I started with [this tutorial](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson.html), and attempted to use a remote source in place of a local one. The relevant block looks like the following:

```js
var map = new Map({
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: "map",
  view: new View({
    center: [-13739617.939346, 6179221.917031],
    zoom: 11
  })
});

map.once("postrender", () => {
  axios.get(jsonUrl).then(({ data } = {}) => {
    const jsonSource = new VectorSource({
      features: new GeoJSON().readFeatures(data, {
        featureProjection: "EPSG:4326"
      })
    });

    const jsonLayer = new VectorLayer({
      source: jsonSource,
      style: jsonStyleFunction
    });

    map.addLayer(jsonLayer);
  });
});
```

When I fail to load, I was able to use console logs to determine that there the breaking point wasn't the get request. I was also able to see the there was the same number of `featureChangeKeys_` in the `jsonSource` const as there were features in my JSON object:

```
featureChangeKeys_:
39: (2) [{…}, {…}]
41: (2) [{…}, {…}]
43: (2) [{…}, {…}]
45: (2) [{…}, {…}]
47: (2) [{…}, {…}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to load your data in a different coordinate reference system (CRS) than the map itself. By default, the map loads in the EPSG:3857 projection, while most GeoJSON is in EPSG:4326.

You can test this out by "looking for Null Island". Pan your map to the latlong, (0, 0), and you might see a small point like the following:

[image]

If you see a small speck like above, then this is certainly the issue. To solve this, you can have Openlayers transform data on the fly by defining the `featureProjection` and `dataProjection` attribute as such:

```js
const jsonSource = new VectorSource({
      features: new GeoJSON().readFeatures(data, {
        dataProjection: "EPSG:4326",
        featureProjection: "EPSG:3857"
      })
    });
```